# GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter - merge Two images over an image

Tags: iphone, ios, gpuimage

I want to merge two images over a image using GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter. How can I do this?

And also i want to give effects to that two images separately..Is it possible??!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at GPUImageFilterGroup? That lets you create a filter which effectively chains other pre-built filters into a single filter; you could just add two instances of GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter.

See GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter and GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter for usage examples.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the details of how to do this? E.g. with code?

Comment: Sorry… I haven't really touched GPUImage in the last year and a half.